# Plot back half sphere with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I have found related questions but none of them is exactly what I want.

With `tikz` I can plot a shaded sphere as follows

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{3}

\path[tdplot_screen_coords] (0,0) circle (\myradius);    
\shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color=gray!50,opacity=1] (0,0) circle (\myradius);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: sphere]

How can I modify the above code, maybe with a suitable `clip`, such that only the back half of the sphere shows?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thank you very much. Any hints on showing the back half of a sphere, shaded from the inside?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=gray!50] (0,0) circle[radius=2 cm] node {Front half};
\shade[ball color=gray!50, shading angle=180] (5,0) circle[radius=2 cm] node {Back half};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two shaded balls with text]

Comment: Ah this was the actual question. Got it

Comment: @Roland: I am not sure at all. Your solution might be the correct one - hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you hpekristiansen, this is the correct answer. My bad for not clearing out enough that I wanted the back half, not the top or bottom one. And for not providing a MWE. So the trick is basically to draw a circle with a suitably oriented light...

Comment: This is why craters look like mounds when lit from the south.  But I digress...

Comment: @MathMax Note that this solution is actually an optical illusion. As John Kormylo already mentioned. It works here because we see the front half and the back half next to each other (assuming the light source comes from above). Once you remove one your brain may make a sphere out of it again.

Comment: @Roland After all, every 3D object we see on the screen is an optical illusion, right?

Answer (score 7):

Another Ti*k*Z 3d solution, slightly different.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}          % 'canvas is...' options
\usetikzlibrary{perspective} % isometric view

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]
% top half
\draw[ball color=gray!50] {[canvas is xy plane at z=0] (135:2) arc (135:315:2)} arc (0:180:2cm);
% bottom half
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\draw[ball color=gray!70,shading angle=180] (0,0) circle (2);
\draw[ball color=gray!50] {[canvas is xy plane at z=0] (315:2) arc (315:135:2)} arc (180:360:2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: better light effects (but more code) using clips:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}          % 'canvas is...' options
\usetikzlibrary{perspective} % isometric view

\newcommand\contour
{%
  {[canvas is xy plane at z=0] (135:2) arc (135:315:2)} arc (0:180:2cm)
}
\newcommand\half
{%
  \begin{scope}
    \clip \contour;
    \fill[ball color=gray!50] (0,0,0) circle (2cm);
  \end{scope}
  \draw \contour;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view]
% top half
\begin{scope}
  \half
\end{scope}
% bottom half
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,rotate=180]
  \half
  \draw[ball color=gray!70,shading angle=180] (0,0) circle (2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. My question was about the back half, not top and bottom half, as in hpekristiansen's answer. Upvoted for your kind effort anyways and for the nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

One possible and simple solution with `arc`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \shade[ball color=gray!50,opacity=1] (0,0) arc (0:-180:1cm and 4mm) arc (180:0:1cm and 1cm);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Since OP clarified what he wants I just want to add one correct solution:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       
    \shadedraw [ball color=gray!50,shading=ball,opacity=1] (0,-1) arc (-90:90:1cm and 10mm);
  
    \shadedraw [ball color=gray!50,shading=ball,opacity=1] (0,0) ellipse (0.5cm and 1cm);
     
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was about the back half, not the top half. The solution by hpekristiansen is the correct one. Upvoted for you kind effort anyways.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested in Asymptote, there is available `unithemisphere` from the 3D module `three`. Just paste the following codes to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click Run. Note that both code use the same projection (same point of view). You may want to change `opacity(.5)` to see the hidden things.

The front half hemisphere is the sphere part with  `x > 0`:

[image]

```
import three;
size(6cm);
currentprojection=orthographic((1,1,.6),zoom=.9);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--2X,red);
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--2Y,green);
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--2Z,blue);

// the front half x>0
draw(rotate(90,Y)*unithemisphere,yellow+opacity(1));
```

and the back half hemisphere is the sphere part with  `x < 0`:

[image]

```
import three;
size(6cm);
currentprojection=orthographic((1,1,.6),zoom=.9);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--2X,red);
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--2Y,green);
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--2Z,blue);

// the back half x<0
draw(rotate(-90,Y)*unithemisphere,yellow+opacity(1));
```

Comment: I didn't know Asymptote, thank you for your answer. My question, however, was about the back half, not top and bottom half. Upvoted anyways for the nice solution and kind effort

Comment: @MathMax how about the back and front hemispheres in my answer now?

Comment: Yup, you nailed it! Thank you once again. I really need to add Asymptote to my graphics arsenal.

Comment: We can construct (closed, with base) hemisphere as in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/559027/140722